# Jade include with parameter

Tags: pug, partial

In an older version of Jade I was able to include partials and pass variables into them like this:

```
!=partial('partials/video', {title:video.title, artist:video.artist})
```

now the partial connotation does not exist any more. How do I achieve the same thing using the include connotations?

Answer (score 31):

You can use [mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) for that. Wrap your include content inside a mixin and call the mixin function in your pug file. See my example below.

**include-file.pug**

```
mixin my-include(title, description)
  h1= title
  p= description
```

**index.pug**

```
include include-file
html
  head
  body
    +my-include('my title', 'my description')
```