# How to pass data in included pug template using node-express

Tags: node.js, templates, express, pug

```
-- header.jade
ul
    li
        a User = #{userName}

-- layout.jade
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    include header

    include index

-- route file: index.js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
            userName: 'Jane Doe'
        });
});
```

how to get the userName value in header jade template which is included in the layout.jade file. i am trying to implement a common header concept for my project.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Take the `return` out of the last line. Also its called `pug` now not `jade`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning your response in wrong way.

Return your response data with needed template like this

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 return res.render('index', {
    userName: 'Jane Doe'
  });
});
```

Comment: Nope, tried that.it does not get pass into separate header.jade but is present in the jade file which is extending the layout.jade.

Comment: As you said you are trying to use common header with title then you need to save your title value  somewhere in client side since your are rendering `index` page not `header.pug`.

Comment: its nor the value of title that needs to be set, i need to set the value of userName which is present in header.pug, and header.pug is included in layout.pug, AND index.pug extends layout.pug. i hope u understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: Ohh sorry!! it's my mismatch but you can get that value if you render that page or just save somewhere and use it

Comment: tried that.. in the end i wrote the content of header.pug into layout.pug itself

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is now the default and variables get passed to included views. If you want, you can also use mix-in functions, see [Jade include with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936197/jade-include-with-parameter) .